# Error using Webpack: Cant seem to set correct path for directive templates

Tags: angularjs, webpack, raw-loader

Here below is a snippet of my directive, before without using webpack I used the templateUrl version, worked fine. Ive included also my webpack.config file. I can't seem to figure this out.

```js
function footerContent() {
  'use strict';

  console.log('footerContent');


  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    template: require('./footer-area.html')
  };
}

// angular
//  .module('alpha')
//  .directive('footerContent', footerContent);

module.exports = function(ngModule) {
  'use strict';

  ngModule.directive('footerContent', footerContent);
};
```

Running Webpack command results in this error, I know its trying to reach the file in the wrong directory but I tried several variations of the paths for the dir with no success :

```
ERROR in . / scripts / Directive / headerContent.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file'
or 'directory'. / header - area.html in / app / scripts / Directive@. / scripts / Directive / headerContent.js 10: 12 - 41

ERROR in . / scripts / Directive / footerContent.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file'
or 'directory'. / footer - area.html in / app / scripts / Directive@. / scripts / Directive / footerContent.js 10: 12 - 41

ERROR in . / scripts / Directive / contentArea.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file'
or 'directory'. / home.html in / app / scripts / Directive@. / scripts / Directive / contentArea.js 10: 12 - 34

ERROR in . / scripts / Directive / socialMediabuttons.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file'
or 'directory'. / social - media - buttons.html in /Users/Tim / Desktop / P / TimothyLombrana / app / scripts / Directive@. / scripts / Directive / socialMediabuttons.js 10: 12 - 50
```

Here is mywebpack config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: why don't use `templateUrl: './footer-area.html'`?

Comment: I saw a video that said that's not the correct way when defining the ddo. It said to only use template: require('./path'), but ill try it.

Comment: may I know why it is incorrect way? usually people do refer the templates by providing their url..

Comment: The video(egghead.io) says when using webpack and the raw-loader(for html), using this version will allow you to move modules to any place in the app without the path breaking. Basically able to move the file without having to go back and set new path.

Comment: Got it, thanks for info(haven't used webpack ever)..

Comment: Your welcome, coming from require, webpack is great! Regardless of this problem.